# Нужно ли тут обособление?

Tags: пунктуация

***Перед въездом в часть***, медики должны сообщить информацию по департаменту.

Answer (score 2):

**Перед въездом в часть** медики должны сообщить информацию по департаменту.

Обстоятельственный оборот в препозиции (детерминант), выраженный падежной формой существительного,  не обособляется.

**Примечание**

Возможно обособление оборотов с производными предлогами (вследствие, ввиду и др.), но как факультативное. Кроме того, в деловом стиле такие обороты также  не обособляются.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая-то не нужна, а вот "сообщить информацию" не смущает? Информацию не сообщают, информацию передают, можно ее и распространять.

Comment: Странно, что Вам не встречалось выражение "сообщить информацию". Оно широко распространено, даже в словаре Кузнецова несколько раз встречается. Чтобы убедить Вас, приведу ещё более распространённое выражение: "сообщить сведения".

Comment: Лучше посмотрите сами у Кузнецова, как много разных глаголов сочетаются со словом "информация".

Comment: @grizzly, а к "сообщить сведения" никаких претензий и нет.

Comment: Замечательно — это уже полшага к принятию и пониманию. Повторюсь, что "сообщить информацию" не раз встречается у Кузнецова.